# problema para acceder con ajax a archivos fuera del la parte publica del host

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema con una aplicación que estoy creando con PHP.
Es una aplicación web que estoy intentando securizar al máximo, por ello he creado una parte privada donde están todos los script de php y otra publica donde estan los script javascript, el css, html, etc
El dominio tiene que apuntar directamente a la carpeta publica. La estructura de carpetas simplificando mucho seria

private

- admin( archivos con los script en php)
- config

public

- index.php
- assets (carpeta con css, javascript, etc)
- images

Como digo, el dominio apunta a la carpeta public y en el archivo index.php cargo sin problemas distintas rutinas que tengo en los archivos de private/admin/  , el problema lo tengo cuando intento  mediante ajax acceder a una rutina de un archivo que tengo en esa misma ruta para hacer una consulta asíncrona, en la consola veo que me dice error 404, archivo no encontrado.
El código de acceso sería este;

```
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function fn_modificar() {

            var str = $("#frm_per").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: '../private/admin/grupos_modificar.php',
                data: str,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#success2').html(" " + data + " ");

                    $("#el_boton").hide();
                    //$("h4").hide();
                },
                error: function () {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success2').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success2 > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                            .append("</button>");
                    $('#success2 > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Uppps! <?= _("el servidor no esta respondiendo") ?>...</strong> <?= _("¡Perdone por las molestias!") ?>");
                    $('#success2 > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                },
            });
        }
        ;

    </script>
```

espero haberme explicado suficientemente bien
¿alguna idea?

Comment: ¿En qué archivo está tu Ajax? Muestra el contenido de `admin` o parte relevante de él.

Comment: Con ajax haces una petición al servidor web. Si el dominio apunta a la carpeta public, sólo podrás acceder a lo que hay en la carpeta public.

Comment: Hola Gracias @juanrpozo  Aunque tu contestación es muy escueta me has hecho sea consciente de que estaba enfocando mal el problema, asi que lo que he creado es un archivo helper en la carpeta public al que llamo desde ajax y este archivo carga el código del scrip de php que sigo manteniendo en la zona private.